# Cimg is increasing the size of the original image

Tags: c++, c++11, size, image-size, cimg

I am using Cimg to modify an image(original size 145 KB). I add few lines of text and save it which is increasing the size the of the image to almost 900KB. So I tried to save the original image itself to see, but that too is saving the image with 900KB. How can I maintain the size or minimize the size of the image being saved. Please suggest a solution to resolve the same.

Comment: Which format is the file ? Formats like jpg have compression parameters. Different parameters result in default file size and the default in Cimg is probably different than what was used when the original image was saved.

Comment: @wohlstad. Thanks for replying... The original file is of bmp format. But while saving I can save it(after adding few texts to the image) in any format. However, The final file size is resulting to almost 900KB irrespective of the format. I tried to resize the image but all the texts become blurred. I am looking for a way to reduce the size of the image without blurring the texts.